# select query for sql

Tags: sql, oracle

## Table description

#### Table Name:- Name condition

### Name    |     Pattern

```
 A  |   %A% or Name like %a%

 B  |   %B% or Name like %b%

 C  |   %C% or Name like %c%

 D  |   %D% or Name like %d%

 E  |   %E% or Name like %e%

 F  |   %F% or Name like %f%

 G  |   %G% or Name like %g%
```

#### Table name:- Employees

### Emp_ID    |     EMP_NAME

```
1   |   Akshay

2   |   Akhil

3   |   Gautam

4   |   Esha

5   |   bhavish

6   |   Chetan

7   |   Arun
```

[Table description] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvOgr.png

Above are my two tables now my query is (in the image)

**Select * from Employees,Name_condition where EMP_NAME like Pattern**

Here the query is correct syntactically but produces wrong output. 
It takes the column Pattern as a string and searches for it in EMP_NAME and it will find nothing.
So my question is how we can take the values present in the Pattern column as a condition and not as a string so that the query will become like this

**Select * from Employees,Name_condition where EMP_NAME like ‘%A%’ or Name like ‘%a%’**
  
what i need is when i pass colunm name(**Pattern**) in the where condition it takes **%A% or Name like %a%** whole as a string but i want that
 **select * from Employees,Name_condition where EMP_NAME like Pattern**
 Here the column name pattern internally must be replace by the value present in the column and the the query produces o/p like this
 
**Select * from Employees,Name_condition where EMP_NAME like ‘%A%’ or Name like ‘%a%’**

Desired Result:-
I expect all the rows in my result which includes **bhavish** but as we see we have a like condition in the column itself like **%B% or Name like %b%**

What i want is when it matches 

**where EMP_NAME like Pattern**

The value of pattern must internally replaced by 

**%B% or Name like %b%** 

and the it produces the output which includes **bhavish** which starts with **b**

Comment: add sample data

Comment: The question is unclear. Please post same sample data and desired result, paying attention to post data as formatted text, [not  screenshots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Is it right that the pattern B contains like '%ab%' or is it a typo? Also, please edit the question to post data as formatted text, even adding the needed result for your sample data

Comment: Yes the pattern B contains like '%ab%'

Comment: **Select * from Employees,Name_condition where EMP_NAME like Pattern**

what i need is when i pass colunm name(Pattern) in the where condition it takes  *%A% or Name like %a%* whole as a string but i want that

**select * from Employees,Name_condition where EMP_NAME like Pattern**
Here the column name **pattern**  internally must be replace by the value present in the column and the the query produces o/p  like this 

**Select * from Employees,Name_condition where EMP_NAME like ‘%A%’ or Name like ‘%a%’**

Comment: As said, the best way to clarify your need is posting sample data and desired result ( as formatted text, so that people con build an example and try some code)

Comment: Can  you please check now if it makes clear sense...

Comment: Better, but not completely clear :). Say you have only the pattern A and G and only the employees 1, 2, 3. All the employees match the pattern A and the 3rd even matches the pattern G. How many rows do you expect from this? And with which values?

Comment: I expect all the rows in my result but as we see we have a like condition in the column itself like **%B% or Name like %b%*
What i want is when it matches 
**where EMP_NAME like Pattern**
the value of pattern must internally replaced by 
**%B% or Name like %b%** 
and the it produces the output which includes **bhavish** which starts with **b**

Comment: Honestly, is it that difficult to post the result you need, starting from your data?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
select * 
from employees 
where  emp_name like '%oh%'
  or   emp_name like '%a%';
```

Good luck.

Comment: Please check my question 
<br/>I want column name after like which itself is a condition.

Answer (score 0):

Try this from [orafaq](http://www.orafaq.com/faq/how_does_one_escape_special_characters_when_writing_sql_queries):

```
SELECT * FROM employees 
WHERE emp_name LIKE '\%a\%' ESCAPE '\';
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not that simple (and it shouldn't be). If you really have to use such tables you have to write a piece of PL/SQL to handle your conditions. 
Two things you have to read about:

- [dynamic sql](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#LNPLS011)
- [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (because you want to prevent it)

Comment: Can you please give me an example of it.

Answer (score -2):

Try to Put && instead of 'And' in condition

Comment: SQL has `AND`, not `&&`.